# PHP More then one comment

Tags: php, forms, cookies

Is there a way to show more comments instead of overwriting the other one?
I was thinking about using a variable with index, so it wouldn't overwrite the other one. 
But I'am not sure if it's possible and where to put the Index.

PHP

```
 <?php
    $name = ""; //Variable aanmaken met waarde
    $comment = "";  //Variable aanmaken met waarde
    $gender = "";  //Variable aanmaken met waarde

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") // Controleer of het formulier verzonden is
    { 
        if(isset($_POST["name"], $_POST["comment"], $_POST["gender"] )) // Controleer of benodigde velden wel ingevuld zijn 
        {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $comment [] = $_POST["comment"];
            $gender = $_POST["gender"];

            $_POST["name"] = "asds";
        }  
        else
        {
            $name = "Niks ingevuld";
            $comment = "Niks ingevuld";
            $gender = "Niks ingevuld";
        }
    }
```

HTML:

### Comment formulier

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <br><br>
   Comment:  <textarea name[]="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
   <br><br>
   Gender:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>  value="male">Male
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

PHP that shows the comment:

```
    <?php
    echo "<h2>Comments:</h2>";
    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";
foreach($data as $comment){

echo $data.'</br>';
    echo "<br>";
    echo $gender;
```

Comment: Where are you storing the comments?

Comment: But how and where are you getting more than one comment?

Comment: @AdamSinclair How is that not relevant? In the code he posted he has only one comment input.

Comment: Hi Traian, I want my comment to show beneath the first comment instead of overwriting it.

@That's right Adam.

Comment: @user4024249 You need to save your comments into a database then. You can't keep them in the memory forever. At a page refresh or window close any previous comments will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, that should work for you:

```
<h2>Comment formulier</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <br><br>
   Comment: <textarea name="comment[]" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
   <br />
   Comment2: <textarea name="comment[]" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
   <br />
   <?php
       if (isset($_POST["comment"]))
           $comment = $_POST["comment"];
       foreach ($comment as $key => $value)
           echo 'comment '.$key.' '.$value.'<br />';
   ?>
   </textarea>
   <br><br>
   Gender:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>  value="male">Male
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: The above method will only work if you have more than one comment fields.

Comment: @RaheelKhan That's exaclty what he asks! Besides it works perfectly with one field!

Comment: Hi, Could you look at my edit, right now it just overwrites the first array[0] instead of making one extra.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out when I get home

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea name[]="comment" rows="5" cols="40">
```

than run the foreach loop after isset condition

```
foreach($data as $comment){

echo $data.'</br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can show more comments by using arrays, Just take your post values in arrays and Print them